# Scan Barcodes ML Kit on Android and send it to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

I'm trying to find the way to scan barcodes and send it to a google sheets through an Android Smartphone. I've tried with the Zxing library but is deprecated.

Is there any website to get info about how to send barcodes to a google sheet using this Google's ML kit??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

you.https://www.crazycodersclub.com/android/how-to-use-google-sheet-as-database-for-android-app-1-insert-operation/

its like to generate google sheet file and save data in it, so that you can scan data and store in it array list and generate sheet file and put data in it.

Comment: Thank you Vineela, I'll take a look to your link :)